# How to add a link to breadcrumb menu

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs

How to add a link to breadcrumb menu? I have a link in my menu. But it's not printed in my breadcrumb. I am using Breadcrumb NavXT plugin in wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add breadcrumb without using any plugin like this. Please add below code into your themes functions.php file.

```
function breadcrumbs($id = null){
?>
<div id="breadcrumbs">
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">Home</a></span> >
    <?php if(!empty($id)): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $id ); ?>" ><?php echo get_the_title( $id ); ?></a> >
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span class="breadcrumb_last"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
</div>
<?php }
```

Now whenever you want to add breadcrumb just call this function like this.

```
<?php breadcrumbs(); ?>
```

Or if there is any inner page like child page or single page u can just pass the parent page id.

```
<?php breadcrumbs($id); ?>
```